# How to Save video file to iOS Files App using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, uikit, avfoundation, uidocumentinteractioncontroller, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

I want to write one or multiple mov/mp4 files to iOS Files App but can not find how to do it with UIDocumentInteractionController. Looking for a sample code to copy files to a subfolder of my app in iOS files app using UIDocumentInteractionController. See sample screenshot to understand what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to create a File Provider extension for your app if you are **storing the files remotely**.

If they are only being stored **locally** on device you can achieve this by (in the Info.plist) either setting the `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` key, or by setting bother the `UIFileSharingEnabled` and `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` keys.

As explained in this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider):

> These keys enable other apps to open and edit the contents of your Documents directory in place. Your files also appear in both the Files app and the document browser. For more information, see the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also need to create a folder for my app. Is there a way to create a folder as well?